# Problema con JSon DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, json, deserialize

Tengo una aplicación que recupera información de una BD para entregarla vía una API JSon a aplicaciones externas que requieren esa información.

Mi problema es con ésta línea de código.

```
T oRetorno = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(StrJSon) ?? default;
```

T representa una clase del tipo:

```
ReturnValue<List<ClsPersonFederalIdBase>>
```

La clase ReturnValue se define de la siguiente manera:

```
public class ReturnValue<T> {
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public T ObjectValue { get; set; }
}
```

Y la clase ClsPersonFederalIdBase se define de la siguiente manera.

```
public class ClsPersonFederalIdBase : IConvertible {

    #region Propiedades
    [JsonProperty]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public int FederalTypeId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string FederalText { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string StrImage1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string StrImage2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public int RefPersonId { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Constructores
    public ClsPersonFederalIdBase(DataRow pDr) {
        PersonId = pDr["PersonId"].ToInt();
        Id = pDr["FederalId"].ToInt();
        FederalTypeId = pDr["FederalIdType"].ToInt();
        FederalText = pDr["FederalIdText"].ToString();
        StrImage1 = ((byte[])pDr["Image1"]).ToImage().ToBase64String();
        StrImage2 = ((byte[])pDr["Image2"]).ToImage().ToBase64String();
        Active = pDr["Active"].ToBool();
    }

    public ClsPersonFederalIdBase() { }
    #endregion

    #region IConvertible
    TypeCode IConvertible.GetTypeCode() {
        return TypeCode.Object;
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    bool IConvertible.ToBoolean(IFormatProvider provider) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    byte IConvertible.ToByte(IFormatProvider provider) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    char IConvertible.ToChar(IFormatProvider provider) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    DateTime IConvertible.ToDateTime(IFormatProvider provider) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    decimal IConvertible.ToDecimal(IFormatProvider provider) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    double IConvertible.ToDouble(IFormatProvider provider) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    short IConvertible.ToInt16(IFormatProvider provider) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    int IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    long IConvertible.ToInt64(IFormatProvider provider) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    sbyte IConvertible.ToSByte(IFormatProvider provider) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    float IConvertible.ToSingle(IFormatProvider provider) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    string IConvertible.ToString(IFormatProvider provider) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    object IConvertible.ToType(Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider) {

        if (conversionType == typeof(ClsPersonFederalId)) {
            return new ClsPersonFederalId(
                PersonId, Id, FederalTypeId, FederalText, StrImage1,
                StrImage2, Active, RefPersonId);
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    ushort IConvertible.ToUInt16(IFormatProvider provider) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    uint IConvertible.ToUInt32(IFormatProvider provider) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    ulong IConvertible.ToUInt64(IFormatProvider provider) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

El error que me genera es el siguiente.

```
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Mensaje = One or more errors occurred. (Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'ColonialModel.ClsPersonFederalIdBase' because the type requires a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'objectValue.$values[0].personId', line 1, position 104.)
  Origen = System.Private.CoreLib
  Seguimiento de la pila:
   en System.ThrowHelper.ThrowAggregateException(List`1 exceptions)
   en System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAllCore(Task[] tasks, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   en System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks)
   en ColonialModel.ClsPersonFederalId.FnGetByPerson(ClsPerson pPerson, ActiveStatus pStatus) en C:\Users\GallegJuG\Documents\Personales\Gabo\Colonial\Apps\Colonial\ColonialModel2\ClsPerson.cs: línea 2605
   en ColonialModel.ClsPerson.get_FederalIds() en C:\Users\GallegJuG\Documents\Personales\Gabo\Colonial\Apps\Colonial\ColonialModel2\ClsPerson.cs: línea 288
   en TestAPI.Views.PersonsView.LbxPersons_DoubleClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) en C:\Users\GallegJuG\Documents\Personales\Gabo\Colonial\Apps\Colonial\TestAPI\Views\PersonsView.cs: línea 123
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnDoubleClick(EventArgs e)
   en System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, WM msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
  Esta excepción se generó originalmente en esta pila de llamadas:
    [Código externo]
    DbManager.ClsRest<T>.FnGetRestServiceDataAsync(string, object, string, bool) en ClsRest.cs
    [Código externo]
    ColonialModel.Utils.FnExecuteAsGet<T>(DbManager.ClsRest<ColonialModel.ReturnValue<T>>, string, object[,]) en Utils.cs
    [Código externo]
    ColonialModel.Utils.FnExecuteApiAsync<T>(string, string, object, ColonialModel.Utils.ApiMethod) en Utils.cs
    [Código externo]
    ColonialModel.ClsPersonFederalId.FnExecuteAsync<T>(string, object, ColonialModel.Utils.ApiMethod) en ClsPerson.cs
    [Código externo]
    ColonialModel.ClsPersonFederalId.FnGetByPersonAsync(ColonialModel.ClsPerson, ColonialModel.ActiveStatus) en ClsPerson.cs
    ...
    [Pila de llamadas truncada]
Excepción interna 1:
JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'ColonialModel.ClsPersonFederalIdBase' because the type requires a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'objectValue.$values[0].personId', line 1, position 104.
```

NOTA: Un fragmento previo del código que se utiliza dentro de la aplicación, obtiene una lista de personas y se ejecuta correctamente. Esencialmente el código que se ejecuta es el mismo, pero usando otras clases como Tipo genérico... incluso dentro de una lista.

La clase es: ClsPersonBase y se define de la siguiente manera:

```
public class ClsPersonBase {

    #region Propiedades
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int GenderId { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public int RefPersonId { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Constructores
    public ClsPersonBase(DataRow pDr) {
        if (pDr != null) {
            Id = pDr["PersonId"].ToInt();
            Name = pDr["Name"].ToString();
            MiddleName = pDr["MiddleName"].ToString();
            LastName = pDr["LastName"].ToString();
            GenderId = pDr["GenderId"].ToInt();
            Active = pDr["Active"].ToBool();
        }
        else {
            Id = 0;
            Name = "";
            MiddleName = "";
            LastName = "";
            GenderId = 0;
            Active = false;
        }
    }

    public ClsPersonBase() {
        Id = 0;
        Name = "";
        MiddleName = "";
        LastName = "";
        GenderId = 0;
        Active = false;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

La única diferencia que observo, es que la clase ClaPersonBase no implementa la interface IConvertible, sin ebmargo esa se la pude a ClsPersonFederalIdBase, debido que C# me la exigía para poder mapearla a su clase hijo, cosa que con ClsPersonBase no me ocurrió (raro), sin embargo son funciones implementadas explícitamente, por lo que no creo que interfieran con el mapeo de la clase. Entonces no entiendo el error :( Ojalá me pueden ayudar.

De antemano, muchas gracias!

EDITADO:
Agrego el JSon que se intenta deserializar.

```
{
    "$id":"1",
    "success":true,
    "errorMessage":null,
    "objectValue":{
        "$id":"2",
        "$values":[
            {
                "$id":"3",
                "personId":1,
                "id":1,
                "federalTypeId":1,
                "federalText":"ABCDE12345",
                "strImage1":"",
                "strImage2":"",
                "active":true,
                "refPersonId":0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Dante:** te agrego un JSon que sí deserializa correctamente. A simple vista no veo diferencia entre uno y otro... y los objetos son muy similares.

Tengo otro objeto definido de la siguiente manera.

```
/*
Clase: ReturnValue (Siempre va ésta clase contenedora)
Que en ObjectValue contiene una lista del tipo
List<ClsFederalType>
*/

/*La clase ClsFederalType se define a través de una clase padre
con la siguiente estructura.*/
public class ClsCatalogBase {
    public static EnmCatalogType LcCatalogType;
    public static string LcStrGetAll, LcStrGetById, LcStrGetIdByCode, LcStrGetIdByName,
        LcStrInsert, LcStrUpdate, LcStrDelete, LcStrCatalogName;

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ClsCatalogBase(DataRow pDr) {
        Id = pDr["Id"].ToInt();
        Code = pDr["Code"].ToString();
        Name = pDr["Name"].ToString();
    }

    public ClsCatalogBase() { }
}

/*El objeto JSon se define de la siguiente manera*/
{
  "$id": "1",
  "success": true,
  "errorMessage": null,
  "objectValue": {
    "$id": "2",
    "$values": [
      {
        "$id": "3",
        "id": 1,
        "code": "INE",
        "name": "Instituto Nacional Electoral"
      },
      {
        "$id": "4",
        "id": 2,
        "code": "ICV",
        "name": "Licencia Conducir"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

y éste objeto sí deserializa correctamente...

Edición: 2022-10-14

Bien, para entender un poco por que no logro entender éste problema, trataré de mostrar la lógica de cómo mi sistema trata de recuperar datos:

Empezaré por decir que tengo una clase genérica llamada: **ClsRest** que se define de la siguiente forma.

```
public class ClsRest<T> {

    public async Task<T> FnGetRestServiceDataAsync(string pStrServiceMethod, object? pObject = default,
        string? pStrQueryParams = default, bool pBolError = true) {

        HttpResponseMessage oResponse;
        HttpContent oContent = null;
        string StrJSon, StrAux;

        //Determinación de si tenemos contenido a pasar en oContent;
        if (pObject != null) {
            StrJSon = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pObject);
            oContent = new StringContent(StrJSon, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        }

        //Al método invocado, le agregamos las variables del QueryString, si aplica
        pStrServiceMethod = pStrServiceMethod.StartsWith("/") ? pStrServiceMethod : string.Concat("/", pStrServiceMethod);
        StrAux = string.Concat(pStrServiceMethod, (pStrQueryParams == null) ? "" : string.Concat("?", pStrQueryParams));

        //Creamos el Cliente HTTP e inicializamos el URI con los valores recolectados en el Método y el QueryString
        //Ésta llamada Creara la instancia LcCliente y establecerá el URI.
        SbInitClient(StrAux);

        //Dependiendo si tenemos Contenido a enviar o no, llamamos a Post o a Get
        if (oContent == null)
            oResponse = await LcClient.GetAsync(LcClient.BaseAddress);
        else
            oResponse = await LcClient.PostAsync(LcClient.BaseAddress, oContent);

        //Validamos la respuesta del servidor
        if (oResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            //Si es satisfactoria, recuperamos el mensaje devuelto
            StrJSon = await oResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        else {
            //Si es erronea, se lanza una excepción en caso de que se haya solicitado
            StrJSon = "";
            if (pBolError)
                throw new Exception(string.Concat("Error al llamar al servidor: ", oResponse.ReasonPhrase));
        }

        //Deserializamos el objeto para retornarlo según el tipo enviado a la clase genérica
        T oRetorno = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(StrJSon) ?? default;

        return oRetorno;
    }
}
```

Bien, ésa es la clase que invoca a mi servicio REST y hasta ahora todo ésto me funciona sin problemas.

`EJECUCIÓN SIN ERRORES`

Lo primero que mostraré, es un ejemplo de una llamada con retorno del tipo List usando las funciones arriba descritas que no me genera problemas.

Tengo una clase llamada Utils, que implementa tres funciones de la siguiente forma.

```
public static class Utils {

    /// <summary>
    /// Esta función se encargará de implementar la llamada a la Clase ClsRest.
    /// Envuelve el tipo de objeto que recibe en su clase genérica T en una clase llamada ReturnValue.
    /// Dicha clase servirá para obtener el mensaje de retorno de la ejecución REST.
    /// Será ésta misma función quién valide la clase de retorno ReturnValue y al final,
    /// sólo devolverá el objeto genéroco T si no hay error.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Tipo genérico que se usará para retornar el valor devuelto por la llamada a REST.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="pStrApiRoute">
    /// URL de la API a ejecutar.
    /// Ejemplo (En éste ejemplo, el valor de ApiRoute es "Person/"): https://localhost/Person/
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="pStrMethod">
    /// Método a ejecutar (Get, Insert, Update, Activate, Etc) Sirve para complementar el URI
    /// Ejemplo (En éste ejemplo, el valor de ApiRoute es "Get/"): https://localhost/Person/Get/
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="pObjParam">
    /// Objéto de parámetros.
    /// Puede ser un array de valores en páres (para enviar en GET)
    /// o puede ser un objeto de una clase específica (Para enviar en POST)
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="pApiMethod">
    /// Método HTTP a usar: Get, Post, Delete, etc.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// Devuelve un objeto de la clase genérica T
    /// </returns>
    /// <exception cref="Exception">
    /// Invoca una excepción desencadenada por la llamada a ClsRest si es requerido
    /// </exception>
    public static async Task<T> FnExecuteApiAsync<T>(
        string pStrApiRoute, string pStrMethod, object pObjParam, 
        ApiMethod pApiMethod = ApiMethod.Get) {

        ClsRest<ReturnValue<T>> oSrv = new ClsRest<ReturnValue<T>>(ClsColonial.AppName, ClsColonial.Module);

        ReturnValue<T>? oRet = null;
        string StrServiceMethod = $"{pStrApiRoute}{pStrMethod}";

        switch (pApiMethod) {
            case ApiMethod.Get:
                oRet = await FnExecuteAsGet(oSrv, StrServiceMethod, (object[,])pObjParam);
                break;
            case ApiMethod.Post:
                oRet = await FnExecuteAsPost(oSrv, StrServiceMethod, pObjParam);
                break;
        }

        if (oRet == null || !oRet.Success) {
            throw new Exception($"Error: {(oRet == null ? "El Retorno es Nulo." : oRet.ErrorMessage)}");
        }

        return oRet.ObjectValue;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Ejecuta la llamada a ClsRest con el Método HTTP Get
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Clase genérica que se usará para el retorno.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="pSrv">
    /// Clase que ejecutará la llamada a REST.
    /// En éste punto, la clase genérica debe ser una clase del tipo ReturnValue, que debe contener una clase genérica del tipo T
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="pStrServiceMethod">Método HTTP a ejecutar</param>
    /// <param name="pArrParams">Parámetros de la llamada GET</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static async Task<ReturnValue<T>> FnExecuteAsGet<T>(ClsRest<ReturnValue<T>> pSrv,
        string pStrServiceMethod, object[,] pArrParams) {

        bool BolValue = false;
        string StrParams = "", StrUrlConcat = "&";

        string[,] pArrStrParam = FnArrayToString(pArrParams);

        foreach (string StrParam in pArrStrParam) {
            StrParams = $"{StrParams}{(BolValue ? "=" : StrParams.Length == 0 ? "" : StrUrlConcat)}{StrParam}";
            BolValue = !BolValue;
        }

        return await pSrv.FnGetRestServiceDataAsync(pStrServiceMethod, pStrQueryParams: StrParams);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Ejecuta la llamada a ClsRest con el Método HTTP Post
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Clase genérica que se usará para el retorno.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="pSrv">
    /// Clase que ejecutará la llamada a REST.
    /// En éste punto, la clase genérica debe ser una clase del tipo ReturnValue, que debe contener una clase genérica del tipo T
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="pStrServiceMethod">Método HTTP a ejecutar</param>
    /// <param name="pObjParam">Objeto a pasar e la llamada POST</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static async Task<ReturnValue<T>> FnExecuteAsPost<T>(ClsRest<ReturnValue<T>> pSrv,
        string pStrServiceMethod, object pObjParam) {

        return await pSrv.FnGetRestServiceDataAsync(pStrServiceMethod, pObject: pObjParam);
    }
}
```

Adicionalmente, agrego la definición de la clase **ReturnValue** que en realidad es muy simple.

```
public class ReturnValue<T> {
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public T ObjectValue { get; set; }
}
```

Bien, hasta aquí son las clases y funciones que utilizo para la recuperación de datos desde REST.

Posteriormente, tengo las clases que me recuperan información, apoyándose de las clases y funciones que describí en las clases **ClsRest** y **Utils**.

La clase **ClsPerson**, entre otras cosas, tiene una función llamada **FnGetAsync**. La clase y la función se definen de la siguiente forma.

```
public class ClsPerson : ClsPersonBase, IClsPerson {

    /* ... Otros Métodos y Funciones ... */

    public static async Task<List<ClsPerson>> FnGetAsync(
        bool? pBolActive = null) {

        string StrMethod = pBolActive == null ?
            "GetAll" : (bool)pBolActive ? "GetActive" : "GetInactive";

        return await Utils.FnExecuteApiAsync<List<ClsPerson>>(
            ApiRoute, StrMethod, new object[,] { });
    }
}
```

Por favor, ten en cuenta que la **ClsPerson** hereda de una clase Base (Que sólo define sus atributos primitivos) y una Interface (Que define sus métodos) La Deserialización de la clase **ClsPerson** se hace usando la clase Base como destino.

La clase Base se define de la siguiente manera.

```
public class ClsPersonBase {

    #region Propiedades
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int GenderId { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public int RefPersonId { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Constructores
    public ClsPersonBase(DataRow pDr) {
        Id = pDr["PersonId"].ToInt();
        Name = pDr["Name"].ToString();
        MiddleName = pDr["MiddleName"].ToString();
        LastName = pDr["LastName"].ToString();
        GenderId = pDr["GenderId"].ToInt();
        Active = pDr["Active"].ToBool();
    }

    public ClsPersonBase() {
        Id = 0;
        Name = "";
        MiddleName = "";
        LastName = "";
        GenderId = 0;
        Active = false;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Como puedes observar en **ClsPerson**, al final de la función **FnGetAsync**, se retorna el valor devuelto por la llamada a la función **FnExecuteAsync** de la clase **Utils** que, como vimos más arriba, define una clase genérica del tipo **T**, a la que se le pasa un **List** del tipo **ClsPerson**.

Hasta aquí todo bien, la llamada a la función **ClsPerson.FnGerAsync** se ejecuta sin errores y me devuelve un objeto del tipo **List** del tipo **ClsPerson**. Aquí no hay errores.

`EJECUCIÓN CON ERROR`

Ahora bien, el problema está en la clase **ClsPersonFederalId**

Nuevamente, la clase **ClsPersonFederalId** se define heredando una clase Base y una Interface

```
public class ClsPersonFederalId : ClsPersonFederalIdBase, IClsPersonFederalId {

    ** ... Otros Métodos y Funciones ... **

    public static async Task<List<ClsPersonFederalId>> FnGetByPersonAsync(
        ClsPerson pPerson, ActiveStatus pStatus = ActiveStatus.Activo) {

        return await Utils.FnExecuteApiAsync<List<ClsPersonFederalId>>(ApiRoute, "GetByPerson",
            new object[,] {
                { "pIntPersonId", pPerson.Id },
                { "pStatus", pStatus }
            });
    }
}
```

Como puedes observar, la clase **ClsPersonFederalId** implementa la función **FnGetByPersonAsync** que retorna una **List** del tipo **ClsPersonFederalId**. Al final de ésta función, se retorna el valor devuelto por la función **FnExecuteApiAsync** de la clase **Utils** (*Misma función y misma clase que en la invocación de ClsPerson*) a la que se le pasa una **List** del tipo **ClsPersonFederalId**.

Como dato adicional, agrego la definción de la clase Base de **ClsPersonFederalId**

```
public class ClsPersonFederalIdBase : IConvertible {

    #region Propiedades
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int FederalTypeId { get; set; }

    public string FederalText { get; set; }

    public string StrImage1 { get; set; }

    public string StrImage2 { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public int RefPersonId { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Constructores
    public ClsPersonFederalIdBase(DataRow pDr) {
        PersonId = pDr["PersonId"].ToInt();
        Id = pDr["FederalId"].ToInt();
        FederalTypeId = pDr["FederalIdType"].ToInt();
        FederalText = pDr["FederalIdText"].ToString();
        StrImage1 = ((byte[])pDr["Image1"]).ToImage().ToBase64String();
        StrImage2 = ((byte[])pDr["Image2"]).ToImage().ToBase64String();
        Active = pDr["Active"].ToBool();
    }

    public ClsPersonFederalIdBase() { }
    #endregion
}
```

Como puedes observar, la implementación de los métodos GET tanto de la clase **ClsPerson** como de la clase **ClsPersonFederalId** esencialmente son los mismos, sin embargo, en **ClsPersonFederalId** es donde me tira el problema y en la otra no, aunque ambas invocan a la función de la clase **Utils** intentando devolver una lista de sus clases bases, una de ellas no me funciona.

Espero ésto ayude a clarificar un poco más mi problema.

Gracias!

Comment: Por favor, ¿puedes [edit] las etiquetas de tu pregunta y poner con que lenguage de programación estás programando?  Así recibirás mejores ayudas, gracias.

Comment: Hecho masterguru. 
Gracias por la recomendación.

Comment: Deberías compartir tu JSON para poder hacer pruebas si el error es con la deserializacion

Comment: Gracias Daniel. Sí lo pensé, pero ya después se me pasó. Igualmente el JSon es muy simple. Ya lo agregué.

Comment: Porque hace ese montón de conversiones en la clase "class ClsPersonFederalIdBase"  que hereda de  IConvertible ???

Comment: "JSon me la exigía para poder mapearla " ????? Hasta donde yo se NewtonSoft no exige ninguna interfaz para mapear nada!!. Aunque bueno, no se si esta usando NewtonSoft!

Comment: Lo lamento, apenas pude responder estos mensajes. Las conversiones son la implementación de la interface IConvertible... en realidad sólo uso la conversión a un Tipo no estándard (La clase ClsPersonFederalId, que hereda de ClsPersonFederalIdBase. Efectivamente, estoy usando NewtonSoft para serializar y deserializar las clases. Gracias por tu tiempo @RichardVíquezPérez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien... ya encontré el problema.

Les comento.

La lógica que había seguido incluía convertir una lista desde List a List. C# no me permitía hacer un CAST directo desde una lista de tipo a otra, por lo que lo único que se me ocurrió fue generar una función que me tomara una lista, le pasara el formato de origen y el formato de destino. Además, no quería crear una función porcada catálogo que tengo disponible, por lo que se me ocurrió generar una función convertidora que recibiera 2 tipos genéricos (TipoDesde y TipoHasta) de ésta manera.

```
T FnConvertir<De, A>(D pObjListaDe, A pObjListaA){
    //Funcion para convertir
}
```

Sin embargo, para hacer el cast de los objetos, C# me exigía usar la Interfaz IConvertible, e implementar los Converts que se ven arriba en la ClsPersonFederalId. pues al parecer esto es lo que me daba problema ya que la implementación de la Interface la puse en la clase Base, el Deserialize al parecer intenta deserializar incluso las propiedades inherentes a la interfaz, por lo que generaba errores.

Eliminé la necesidad de la Interface, retiré la interface de la clase base y VOILÁ!... eso hizo el truco.

En fin, Muchas Gracias!!

Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Es muy simple: el json no se corresponde con la estructura con la que intentas des-serealizar. A simple vista se evidencia que:

1. Segun la definicion "ReturnValue<List<ClsPersonFederalIdBase>>", "objectValue" es una lista, no un objeto como se ve en el json.
2. "ClsPersonFederalIdBase" no tiene una definicion para "$values" como el array de objetos que tiene el "objectValue" del json.

   ```
    {
       "$id":"1",
       "success":true,
       "errorMessage":null,
       "objectValue":{
          "$id":"2",
          "$values":[
             {
                "$id":"3",
                "personId":1,
                "id":1,
                "federalTypeId":1,
                "federalText":"ABCDE12345",
                "strImage1":"",
                "strImage2":"",
                "active":true,
                "refPersonId":0
             }
          ]
       }
    }
   ```

Comment: Hola Dante, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Efectivamente, en la definición de ReturnValue, ObjectValue es una lista del tipo List<ClsPersonFederalId>. Ahora bien, el objeto ClsPersonFederalId se define conforme a la definición del primer nodo en $Values. Según la estructura JSon los corchetes indican una lista de objetos en su interior, todos agrupados por llave y separados por comas, entonces me parece que el JSon si define una lista, no?... una disculpa, ya ando algo mareado con ésto.

Comment: edite al final de mi pregunta un comentario para clarificar un poco más.

Comment: En ese caso, la List<ClsPersonFederalId> debe ser una propiedad de "ObjectValue". Te falta la definición de "ObjectValue" que es un objeto que contiene (entre otras.cosas) una List<ClsPersonFederalId> como "$Values"

Comment: Claro, en realidad ObjectValue es un un objeto de tipo Genérico, de manera tal que en ese objeto se pueda devolver ya sea un objeto único, o una lista de objeto definida por List<T>

Comment: Si, sé que es de tipo generico. Por eso, no puedes pasarlo como un List<T>. Deberia ser un T, y que el T que de pases sea un objeto que contenga un List<T>

Comment: Uhm Reviso y vuelvo con lo que encontré. Lamento la tardanza en responder, tuve un día ajetreado.

Comment: Bien, revisé lo que me dices y, sigo sin dar pié con bola. Quizá ya estoy tan enredado que simplemente no veo algo tan simple... qué se yo. quisiera explicarte paso a paso lo que estoy haciendo de manera un poco más gráfica, pero por acá es imposible.

Comment: Reeditaré mi pregunta para darte más detalle... Si aún tienes tiempo y ánimo, agradezco el apoyo.

Comment: Listo... agregué los detalles... Mil gracias!